# Django. Access list index in child for loop

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

How can I change the accessed index of an inner for loop list based on a counter from the outer loop? In normal python I would do something like

```
parent_list = ['One','Two','Three']
child_list = ['A','B','C']

for idx, item in enumerate(parent_list):
    for child_item in child_list[idx]:
        print(str(idx), item, child_item)
```

I've been looking at using with and forloop.counters but I either run into the index not being accessed or index not changing.  This is what I currently have.

```
    {% for item in payout_items %}
        {% with forloop.counter0 as outer_counter %}
        <h2>{{ item.market_place }} on {{ item.entry_date }}:
            {% for item in royalty_items.outer_counter %}
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ item.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ item.entry_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.market_place }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
```

If I change

```
{% for item in royalty_items.outer_counter %}
```

to

```
{% for item in royalty_items.0 %}
```

I get the first index repeated many times.   I can see that outer_counter is incrementing from the output but just need royalty_items to increment the accessed index as well.

As requested the view is

```
    detail_object = AccountingPeriod.objects.get(pk=detail_id)
    payout_items = Payout.objects.filter(sales_period_start__range=[detail_object.period_start, detail_object.period_end])

    royalty_items = []
    for payout in payout_items:
        temp = Royalty.objects.filter(entry_date__range=[payout.sales_period_start, payout.sales_period_end]).filter(market_place=payout.market_place)
        print(str(payout.sales_period_start) + " - " + str(payout.sales_period_end) + " - " + payout.market_place + " = " + str(len(temp)))
        royalty_items.append(temp)
```

And the following render call is passed.

```
render(request, 'royalties/accounting_period/summary.html', {'detail_object': detail_object, 'payout_items': payout_items, 'royalty_items': royalty_items})
```

Solution: I created a template filter but feel there should be a more elegant answer.

```
@register.filter()
def getRoyaltySet(royalty_items, outer_counter):
    return royalty_items[outer_counter]
```

Comment: Please share the related view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add this to the items, so:

```
detail_object = get_object_or_404(AccountingPeriod, pk=detail_id)
payout_items = Payout.objects.filter(
    sales_period_start__range=(
        detail_object.period_start,
        detail_object.period_end,
    )
)
for payout in payout_items:
    temp = Royalty.objects.filter(
        entry_date__range=(payout.sales_period_start, payout.sales_period_end),
        market_place=payout.market_place,
    )
    print(
        f'{payout.sales_period_start} - {payout.sales_period_end} - {payout.market_place} = {len(temp)}'
    )
    payout.royalities = temp
```

Then you can access this through `.royalities`:

```
{% for item in payout_items %}
    <h2>{{ item.market_place }} on {{ item.entry_date }}</h2>:
        {% for subitem in item.royalites %}
            <!-- … -->
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does the tuple/list variation on the Payout objects filter make any real difference?   I'm going to guess performance overheads?

Comment: This is a better solution than what I achieved.   Although I'm guessing you meant {% for item in item.royalties %} and not {% for item in payout_items.royalites %}     Thank you :)   I'm happy to accept this as an answer.

Comment: @ByteInsight: aarrrrggghhhh, yes. Probably also better to use `{% for subitem ... %}` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forloop.parentloop to get to the outer forloop

```
{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}
```

You can even chain them if you have nested loops:

```
{{ forloop.parentloop.parentloop.counter }}
```

If you wanna absolutely use your own index you can access the dictionary with `.items`:

```
{% for key, value in mydict.items %}
    {% for key2, value2 in otherdict.items %}
        <div>{{ key }} - {{ key2 }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried a number of combinations of the parentloop suggestions but the issue was the same. The child/inner for loop would not recognise the counter changing.   I'm not sure about your second suggestion as I have a list of dictionaries not a dictionary.    My Django is rusty so I appreciate it might not be best practice!